# how to capture a class element by this in native javascript

Tags: javascript, php, dom

Hello every one in stackoverflow,

I want to create a function in javascript that capture the user_box class and get the id attribute value
then change the backgroundColor of the user_box class that i clicked only not all

i want to do that with native javascript.... not any library like jquery

```
<?php foreach($description AS $descriptions): ?>

<div onclick="" class="user_box" id="<?php echo $descriptions->name; ?>">
  <?php echo $descriptions->all; ?>
</div

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: *get the id attribute*: you did not describe what you want to happen with the id attribute. If nothing, then there is no reason to capture it.

Comment: Did any of the answers meet your needs? Could you give some feed back?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing an html like this:

```
<div onclick="updateBackgroundColor(this);" class="user_box" id="...">
  <!-- ... -->
</div
```

Try this javascript:

```
function updateBackgroundColor(element) {
  console.log(element.id);
  element.style['background-color'] = "whatever_color";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `click` event on div that have `class` user_box and get the `id attribute` which ever div was clicked

```
$('.user_box').click(function (e) {
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DOM [**`getElementsByClassName`**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) to get elements by class.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
   elements[i].addEventListener("click", myOnClickFunction);
```

or better use jQuery/Zepto [**`on`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```
$(".example").on("click", myOnClickFunction)`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the click event on the document and then check the actual element that was clicked has the class of interest.

Here is some JavaScript code you could use:

```js
document.onclick = function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('user_box')) {
        var id = e.target.id;
        console.log('clicked id:', id);
        // get previous element that has special background
        var selected = document.querySelector('.highlight');
        // ...remove the highlight from previously selected element
        if (selected) selected.classList.remove('highlight');
        // ... and put the highlight on on this one:
        e.target.classList.add('highlight');
    }
};
```

```css
.user_box {
    border: 1px solid;
}
.highlight {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="user_box" id="myid1">
  div number 1 - click me
</div>
<div class="user_box" id="myid2">
  div number 2 - click me
</div>
<div class="user_box" id="myid3">
  div number 3 - click me
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this very simple code, that changes user_box background onClick and console id attribute.

```
<div onClick="usbo()" class="user_box" id="<?php echo $descriptions->name; ?>"></div>

function usbo(){
var usbx = document.querySelector(".user_box");
usbx.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
console.log(usbx.getAttribute('id'));
}
```